# A more efficient way of getting the nlargest values of a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to get the top 5 values of a column of my dataframe.

A sample of the dataframe is given below. In fact the original dataframe has thousands of rows.

```
Row(item_id=u'2712821', similarity=5.0)
Row(item_id=u'1728166', similarity=6.0)
Row(item_id=u'1054467', similarity=9.0)
Row(item_id=u'2788825', similarity=5.0)
Row(item_id=u'1128169', similarity=1.0)
Row(item_id=u'1053461', similarity=3.0)
```

The solution I came up with is to sort all of the dataframe and then to take the first 5 values. (the code below does that)

```
items_of_common_users.sort(items_of_common_users.similarity.desc()).take(5)
```

I am wondering if there is a faster way of achieving this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RDD.top` method with `key`:

```py
from operator import attrgetter

df.rdd.top(5, attrgetter("similarity"))
```

There is a significant overhead of `DataFrame` to `RDD` conversion but it should be worth it.