# Get Top 3 values for every key in a RDD in Spark

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, lambda, pyspark, rdd

I'm a beginner with Spark and I am trying to create an RDD that contains the top 3 values for every key, (Not just the top 3 values). My current RDD contains thousands of entries in the following format:

```
(key, String, value)
```

So imagine I had an RDD with content like this:

```
[("K1", "aaa", 6), ("K1", "bbb", 3), ("K1", "ccc", 2), ("K1", "ddd", 9),
("B1", "qwe", 4), ("B1", "rty", 7), ("B1", "iop", 8), ("B1", "zxc", 1)]
```

I can currently display the top 3 values in the RDD like so:

```
("K1", "ddd", 9)
("B1", "iop", 8)
("B1", "rty", 7)
```

Using:

```
top3RDD = rdd.takeOrdered(3, key = lambda x: x[2])
```

Instead what I want is to gather the top 3 values for every key in the RDD so I would like to return this instead:

```
("K1", "ddd", 9)
("K1", "aaa", 6)
("K1", "bbb", 3)
("B1", "iop", 8)
("B1", "rty", 7)
("B1", "qwe", 4)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832153/a-more-efficient-way-of-getting-the-nlargest-values-of-a-pyspark-dataframe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to groupBy the `key` and then you can use `heapq.nlargest` to take the top 3 values from each group:

```
from heapq import nlargest
rdd.groupBy(
    lambda x: x[0]
).flatMap(
    lambda g: nlargest(3, g[1], key=lambda x: x[2])
).collect()

[('B1', 'iop', 8), 
 ('B1', 'rty', 7), 
 ('B1', 'qwe', 4), 
 ('K1', 'ddd', 9), 
 ('K1', 'aaa', 6), 
 ('K1', 'bbb', 3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to converting your `rdd` to a DataFrame, you can define a Window to partition by the `key` and sort by the `value` descending. Use this Window to compute the row number, and pick the rows where the row number is less than or equal to 3.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pyspark.sql.Window

w = Window.partitionBy("key").orderBy(f.col("value").desc())

rdd.toDF(["key", "String", "value"])\
    .select("*", f.row_number().over(w).alias("rowNum"))\
    .where(f.col("rowNum") <= 3)\
    .drop("rowNum")
    .show()
```

Comment: Thanks pault it was a good answer, but using a Dataframe wasn't an option.