# Pyspark: select top k entries in Dataframe, and break ties randomly

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe which records the rank of item for each user, where there can be ties in rank. For those user-item pairs with ties, I want to break ties randomly for each user when select top k entries.

e.g. In this example, k = 3.

input:

```
+-------+-------+----+
| user  | item  |rank|
+-------+-------+----+
|      1|      1|   1|
|      1|      2|   2|
|      2|      1|   1|
|      2|      3|   1|
|      2|      2|   2|
|      2|      4|   2|
|      3|      2|   1|
|      3|      4|   1|
|      3|      1|   2|
|      3|      3|   2|
+-------+-------+----+
```

One desired output is like:

```
+-------+-------+----+
| user  | item  |rank|
+-------+-------+----+
|      1|      1|   1|
|      1|      2|   2|
|      2|      1|   1|
|      2|      3|   1|
|      2|      2|   2|
|      3|      2|   1|
|      3|      4|   1|
|      3|      1|   2|
+-------+-------+----+
```

Or below is good, and so does another two combinations (not listed here)

```
+-------+-------+----+
| user  | item  |rank|
+-------+-------+----+
|      1|      1|   1|
|      1|      2|   2|
|      2|      1|   1|
|      2|      3|   1|
|      2|      4|   2|
|      3|      2|   1|
|      3|      4|   1|
|      3|      1|   2|
+-------+-------+----+
```

Browsed all spark.sql.functions, didn't find anything quite useful, nor from Google.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `row_number` is your friend in this situation

Comment: Use `row_number` as shown in the dupe link (`withColumn("rowNumber", row_number.over(Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy("rank")))`). Then select the rows where the row number is less than k, something like: `df.where(col("rowNumber") < k).sort("user", "rowNumber").drop("rowNumber")`

Comment: Here is an example of what I described in my previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49714042/5858851