# Get top values based on compound key for each partition in Spark RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I want to use the following rdd

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([("K1", "e", 9), ("K1", "aaa", 9), ("K1", "ccc", 3), ("K1", "ddd", 9),
("B1", "qwe", 4), ("B1", "rty", 7), ("B1", "iop", 8), ("B1", "zxc", 1)])
```

to get the output

```
[('K1', 'aaa', 9),
 ('K1', 'ddd', 9),
 ('K1', 'e', 9),
 ('B1', 'iop', 8),
 ('B1', 'rty', 7),
 ('B1', 'qwe', 4)]
```

I referred to [Get Top 3 values for every key in a RDD in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713886/get-top-3-values-for-every-key-in-a-rdd-in-spark) and used the following code

```
from heapq import nlargest
rdd.groupBy(
    lambda x: x[0]
).flatMap(
    lambda g: nlargest(3, g[1], key=lambda x: (x[2],x[1]))
).collect()
```

However, I can only derive

```
[('K1', 'e', 9),
 ('K1', 'ddd', 9),
 ('K1', 'aaa', 9),
 ('B1', 'iop', 8),
 ('B1', 'qwe', 7),
 ('B1', 'rty', 4)]
```

How shall I do?

Comment: Do you want the keys to be sorted? Sorting is an computationally expensive operation. Spark shuffles items for performance, so the order is arbitrary most of the times.

Comment: Yeah, I want them to be sorted. How shall I do to convert the output derived from that code to the one I finally need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a sorting problem actually, but `sorting` is a computationally very expensive process due to `shuffling`. But you can try:

```
rdd2 = rdd.groupBy(
    lambda x: x[0]
).flatMap(
    lambda g: nlargest(3, g[1], key=lambda x: (x[2],x[1]))
)

rdd2.sortBy(lambda x: x[1], x[2]).collect()
# [('K1', 'aaa', 9), ('K1', 'ddd', 9), ('K1', 'e', 9), ('B1', 'iop', 8), ('B1', 'qwe', 4), ('B1', 'rty', 7)]
```

I have sorted it using the first and second value of the tuples.

Also note, `q` comes before `r` alphabetically. So your mentioned expected output is off and misleading.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I have revised my question along what you commented. Following your code, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open for dataframe , you can use `windows` function with `rank`

Inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397796/retrieve-top-n-in-each-group-of-a-dataframe-in-pyspark)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("K1", "e", 9),
    ("K1", "aaa", 9),
    ("K1", "ccc", 3),
    ("K1", "ddd", 9),
    ("B1", "qwe", 4),
    ("B1", "rty", 7),
    ("B1", "iop", 8),
    ("B1", "zxc", 1)], ['A', 'B', 'C']
    )

w = Window.partitionBy('A').orderBy(df.C.desc())
df.select('*', F.rank().over(w).alias('rank')).filter("rank<4").drop('rank').show()


+---+---+---+
|  A | B | C|
+---+---+---+
| B1 | iop | 8|
| B1 | rty | 7|
| B1 | qwe | 4|
| K1 | e | 9|
| K1 | aaa | 9|
| K1 | ddd | 9|
+---+---+---+
```